# Not able to receive message of 10 bytes using native messaging

Tags: c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have created a simple chrome extension in order to interact with a windows native application through chrome native messaging.

I am able to send and receive messages between browser and application. But if the length of the message sent from native application is 10 or 2560, the message is not getting received in extension's onmessage event listener.

Native app code

```
char *test = "{\"tes\":\"\"}";
unsigned int tLen = strlen(test);
cout<< char(((tLen>>0) & 0xFF))
    << char(((tLen>>8) & 0xFF))
    << char(((tLen>>16) & 0xFF))
    << char(((tLen>>24) & 0xFF));
cout << test << flush;
```

If I assign `char *test = "{\"test\":\"\"}"` (with the extra t), it's working fine.

I have no idea what is the cause of this issue.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Please rephrase your question. The problem is not clear, because you don't explain what is not working

Comment: i'm sorry there is a mistake in the sentence. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

The way you pass the data length is incorrect and will also fail on long messages. Instead, try this:

```
char *test = "{\"tes\":\"\"}";
unsigned int tLen = strlen(test);
cout.write((char*)&tLen , 4);
cout << test << flush;
```

Comment: Then maybe this will help - https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/AuKYO6Nn8mk/tXHclfBS78QJ